# How to dynamically load python modules and call method on each of them?

Tags: python, design-patterns, architecture

Python beginner here. Let's say I have three methods for scraping websites. Let's call them `scrape_site_a`, `scrape_site_b`, and `scrape_site_c`. I want to run each of these but I'd like to define them in such a way that I can call them dynamically without calling each by name. Ideally I'd like to just load all modules in a directory and call the same method on each of them. My attempt so far is the following:

**site_a.py**

```
def scrape():
    # scrape the site
```

**site_b.py**

```
def scrape():
    # scrape the site
```

**site_c.py**

```
def scrape():
    # scrape the site
```

I have the `__init__.py` setup such that I can do the following:

**scrape.py**

```
from sites import *

site_a.scrape()
site_b.scrape()
site_c.scrape()
```

I would like to do something like:

```
for site in sites:
    site.scrape()
```

I realize that there is a fundamental programming concept I'm not understanding here and I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to do this using the approach I'm taking?
2. Is there a better approach? Why?

Comment: Use classes as the names pad instead of modules.

Comment: what you are looking for is something like OSGi (but it is too large of a framework to explain in one sitting).

Answer (score 1):

The following scans a given directory, loads each `.py` file in it, and calls the module's `scrape` method if it exists.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join

scraper_dir = "./scrapers"

for scraper_name in listdir(scraper_dir):
    if scraper_name.endswith(".py"):
        with open(join(scraper_dir, scraper_name)) as scraper_file:
            scraper_globals = {}              # this will hold scraper's globals
            scraper_module = exec(scraper_file.read(), scraper_globals)
            if "scrape" in scraper_globals:   # we have a scrape method
                scrape_method = scraper_globals["scrape"]
                callable(scrape_method) and scrape_method()    # call it
```

Comment: This answer is a bit crude but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sites import site_a,site_b,site_c
sites = [site_a,site_b,site_c]
for site in sites:
    site.scrape()
```

I guess might be what you are asking for

```
from sites import *
for item in globals():
    if item.startswith("site_") and hasattr(globals()[item],'scrape'):
       globals()[item].scrape()
```

introspection like this is kinda dicey though ... reader beware

Comment: This is close, but I'd like it to be all dynamically. Ideally, I'd like to load all modules in a directory and call a method in each of those modules (each method has the same name). I've updated my question to be more clear on that

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module for stuff like this.

```py
import inspect
modules = [mod for mod in globals() if inspect.ismodule(eval(mod))]
```

Will give you everything that's a module in your namespace. You should be able to see how to modify this to be more specific, if you want. The trick is running eval to turn a string of a name into a reference to some object, which may be a module.